# chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes availability for force-installed PWAs in chrome enterprise

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, enterprise, kiosk

I'm trying to determine if I can access any browser api for chrome OS that will allow me to identify the device that its running on when the application has been force-installed in kiosk mode as a PWA.

Answer (score 0):

We're running into exactly the same issue right now. The correct path seems to be to create a PWA and to connect it to a (pre-installed) extension that has access to the `enterprise.deviceAttributes`:
See https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration:

> "If there is a capability that your Chrome App has that the regular web platform can't provide, it might be available as an extension API. In this case, you use a progressive web app together with an externally connectable extension your web app can send messages to."

`enterprise.deviceAttributes` are only accessible if the calling App/Site is pre-installed to the device and not loaded dynamically, so it cannot run in the PWA by design.

But with this tutorial, it seems possible:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

We're looking into that right now and will post our progess here.

Comment: Our foray into extension land hit a dead end. Extensions aren’t installed in kiosk mode. 
These apis are on googles roadmap under the code name project FUGU

Comment: Thanks for that insight. We read about [FUGU](https://www.chromium.org/teams/web-capabilities-fugu) also. However, the use of the enterprise API is limited to [force-installed extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes), so in our understanding, it cannot be run from a PWA.
At the moment, we are really unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: We have now raised a support request for FUGU at the Chromium Bug Tracker:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1095088#c2

Comment: Apparently, this is supposed to be the solution to the above question: Apparently. it's not yet production ready and it will only be available on devices that update to recent Chrome OS versions. https://github.com/WICG/WebApiDevice